# Virtualbox host io cache applying scenarios

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, sata, cache

Virtualbox docs [says](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch05.html#iocaching) that using host io cache for sata controller may be a risk of system performance.

At the same time, on my case I see advantage of using host io cache - DisckCrystalMark reports up 10x time better perfomance when host io cache turned on for sata controller.

I googled a lot and found that question is a bit tricky, because it depends on a lot of nuances. Such as vdi type, size, may be storing files types, size, charater of access, etc, etc.

Lets say, I have a CRM app on guest that use file based storage (270 files, 3 GBytes size). Should I add separate sata controller to my VM, then turn on host io cache for it, create separate vdi (lets say 10 GBytes), connect it to that "cached controller", move crm-app file storage to that disk? And leave uncached controller that has main system drive?

Or I can just turn on host caching fot whole system on first vm sata controller?

What is pros and cons in each of these cases?

**And finaly, what is right scenarios for using or not using host io cache? When should I use host io cache with no risk of troubles?**

PS:

Host:
Ubuntu 14 server with 68 GB of RAM
HDD Raid 1
Intel Xeon E5520 x 2 (2 * 4 cores)
Virtualbox 4.3.30

Guest:
Windows 2012R2 
4 cores, 32 GB of RAM, Single SATA controller with single vdi-type standart disk.

With host io cache turned off results is:

```
   Sequential Read (Q= 32,T= 1) :   123.458 MB/s
  Sequential Write (Q= 32,T= 1) :    97.999 MB/s
  Random Read 4KiB (Q= 32,T= 1) :     6.899 MB/s [  1684.3 IOPS]
 Random Write 4KiB (Q= 32,T= 1) :     2.131 MB/s [   520.3 IOPS]
         Sequential Read (T= 1) :   122.048 MB/s
        Sequential Write (T= 1) :    85.759 MB/s
   Random Read 4KiB (Q= 1,T= 1) :     1.597 MB/s [   389.9 IOPS]
  Random Write 4KiB (Q= 1,T= 1) :     1.652 MB/s [   403.3 IOPS]
```

But with host io cache turned on I have:

```
   Sequential Read (Q= 32,T= 1) :   501.050 MB/s
  Sequential Write (Q= 32,T= 1) :   552.461 MB/s
  Random Read 4KiB (Q= 32,T= 1) :    26.325 MB/s [  6427.0 IOPS]
 Random Write 4KiB (Q= 32,T= 1) :    21.424 MB/s [  5230.5 IOPS]
         Sequential Read (T= 1) :   653.452 MB/s
        Sequential Write (T= 1) :   603.009 MB/s
   Random Read 4KiB (Q= 1,T= 1) :    16.561 MB/s [  4043.2 IOPS]
  Random Write 4KiB (Q= 1,T= 1) :    14.950 MB/s [  3649.9 IOPS]
```

So where is the truth?

Here links I googled, there are some contradictory results:

- https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/6045
- h__ps://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=61428

Comment: Good question, I asked a similar one here: https://superuser.com/q/1296927/166906. The interesting thing is that the host io cache slowed things down for me quite a bit.